# StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Overlay -> Injector]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Overlay -> Injector]

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to run my project but from nowhere this error will appear

[image: I am trying to run my project but from nowhere this error will appear]

this is my package.json

[image: package.json]

[image]

my app.module.ts
[image]
I don't know if anyone has this problem. have you been able to fix it?

Comment: are you trying to use a custom built service?  if so this error might be related to not importing it in your app.module & or component files

Comment: i'm inject my services in this way @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})

Comment: can you setup a stackbliz / show code

Comment: @JulianaTorres : You need to share some code. Can you try importing `OverlayModule ` in import section of `app.module.ts` from >>  `import { OverlayModule } from "@angular/cdk/overlay";`

Comment: I'm change how I import the services, I put all my services in app.module.ts and NgModule providers and now working, maybe is an issue with  @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})